# Assuming assembly reference 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have the following warning in all my code:

[Warning in Visual studio 2015 community edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF9Gk.png)

Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp    deploy-node-libraries", "gulp sass", "gulp min" ]
   }
}
```

As you see I included "System.Runtime": "4.1.0" like a dependency as suggested in previous versions like a fix, but it doesn't work.
My environment is: Windows 7 Pro - Service pack 1 - Core I7, Visual studio 2015 comunity edition - Asp.Net Core Project Template

The project actually compiles but all the lines where I call and class from EntityFramework core are underlined and IISExpress can't serve the page.

Comment: Can you try adding a `runtimes` setting and specifying the runtime you want to use?

Comment: i didn;t have time to compare i will do later but when you use the template with authentication it creates all the references to Entityframework and alls these erros dissappear... but if you use the template without authentication a go through the steps described in MSDN to include entity framework the errors appear again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, here is how I fixed mine:

Try to run:

```
nuget.exe locals all -clear
```

In the nuget cli to clear your local cache.

Then in the cli, type:

```
dotnet restore
```

Then add your runtimes in the project json and get rid of `"type": "build"`
in:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "build" <= remove that line
},
```

I have also set the version to 1.0.1.
I have installed the 1.0.0-preview2-003131 of the SDK as well and have set my global.json file accordingly:

```
"sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
}
```

In each project.json of my 3 projects, I have

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  }
```

And my version of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" is "1.0.1", so is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" (1.0.1)

If that still does not work, try to reinstall the [latest SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) (1.0.0-preview2-003131) and check that you have:

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 .NET Core 1.0.1
- VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2

More info about the update can be seen [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/13/asp-net-core-sept-2016-patch/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `global.json` was the important part for me (I'm using VS Code and I'm running an ASP.NET Core 1.1 app on `netcoreapp1.1`).

Comment: `dotnet restore` did not work for me! It failed spectacularly being unable to access some directory deep within my `Windows\System` folders, even in Admin mode. Compiling yielded an application with over seven thousand errors where none existed before. However, keeping my wits about me, I revisited the [.NET Core Download Page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015) and re-installed. Success! No errors, no "Assuming..." warnings.

Comment: A lot has happened since that post, dotnet 1.1.0 is out now and as some suggested you should just simply try to reinstalling everything if you are still in 1.0. Version 1.1.0 also requires you to install a new runtime. Go the the .NET Core download page and go to the current tab to download the latest.